# Umbrella-Header uses wrong import syntax after `pod install`

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods, header-files

I am developing a [local Expo module](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/#adding-a-new-module-to-an-existing-application) in which I am using a 3rd party Framework.

My `.podspec` looks something like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  # root specification

  s.dependency 'ExpoModulesCore'
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/MyLocalFramework.framework'
  s.public_header_files = "Frameworks/MyLocalFramework.framework/Headers/*"

  # Swift/Objective-C compatibility
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES',
    'SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE' => 'wholemodule'
  }

  s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,mm,swift,hpp,cpp}"
end
```

After running `pod install` in my prebuilded iOS app, which implements my module, I am able to import and use `MyLocalFramework` in my Objective-C and Swift files without issues.

However, once I try to run my app with `npx expo run:ios` I get a build error saying an import in my `ModuleName-umbrella.h` failed. There it tries to import the Frameworks headers via the `"Header.h"` syntax (this was generated after `pod install`).

Now, when I manually change the imports using the `<MyLocalFramework/Header.h>` syntax I can build and run the app without issues. My question is: Why does `pod install` use the "" import syntax here instead of <>? I don't want to manually change the imports every time I run `pod install`.

Additional information:
Under my modules `Build Phases > Headers > Project` I specified the `ModuleName-umbrella.h` as well as the `MyLocalFramework` headers.

Comment: I suggest to use SPM and it's commands

Comment: @Cy-4AH I would love to but I have no choice. I have to implement this framework which is only available locally and written in Objective-C.

Comment: There are no problems to create frameworks written in Objective-C with SPM

Comment: I am not the one who created this framework, thus I have no control over it @Cy-4AH